# Read XML with Python tree.getroot

Tags: python, xml

I am new to Python, I have this XML and this code. This is an invoice, where "SalesOrderRet" is the header and "SalesOrderLineRet" is each line of the invoice. The problem that I have is I don't know how to read the SalesOrderLineRet individually for each header. The code that I have here is adding me all the "SalesOrderLineRet" from the entire XML and not just one for the header.

```
def read_xml():
tree = ET.parse('LastResponse.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
form_data = {}
collection = db["tracking"]
for item in root.iter('SalesOrderRet'):
WO = item.find('RefNumber').text
TimeCreatedQB = item.find('TimeCreated').text
Client = item.find('CustomerRef/FullName').text
for items in root.iter('SalesOrderLineRet'):
descrip = getattr(items.find('Desc'), 'text', None)
```

Comment: you may need `find_all` and `for`-loop

Comment: you have wrong indentation - so your code is useless for us. And you should add example data from xml so we could see how it looks like.

Answer (score 1):

For an XML file like this,

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
    <SalesOrderRet>
        <SalesOrderLineRet>
            <RefNumber>1</RefNumber>
            <TimeCreated>0:00</TimeCreated>
            <CustomerRef>
                <FullName>John Doe</FullName>
            </CustomerRef>
        </SalesOrderLineRet>
        <SalesOrderLineRet>
            <RefNumber>2</RefNumber>
            <TimeCreated>0:00</TimeCreated>
            <CustomerRef>
                <FullName>Jack Doe</FullName>
            </CustomerRef>
        </SalesOrderLineRet>
    </SalesOrderRet>
    <SalesOrderRet>
        <SalesOrderLineRet>
            <RefNumber>3</RefNumber>
            <TimeCreated>0:00</TimeCreated>
            <CustomerRef>
                <FullName>Mary Doe</FullName>
            </CustomerRef>
        </SalesOrderLineRet>
        <SalesOrderLineRet>
            <RefNumber>4</RefNumber>
            <TimeCreated>0:00</TimeCreated>
            <CustomerRef>
                <FullName>Susan Doe</FullName>
            </CustomerRef>
        </SalesOrderLineRet>
    </SalesOrderRet>
</data>
```

This function should read the tags and attributes individually. If not already, index each `<SalesOrderRet>` tag and store the individual attributes under that index.

```py
def get_xml(filename):
    tree = ET.parse(filename)
    root = tree.getroot()

    for SalesOrderRet in root:
        print(SalesOrderRet.tag, SalesOrderRet.attrib)

        for SalesOrderLineRet in SalesOrderRet.iter('SalesOrderLineRet'):
            print('  ', SalesOrderLineRet.tag, SalesOrderLineRet.attrib)

            WO = SalesOrderLineRet.find('RefNumber').text
            TimeCreatedQB = SalesOrderLineRet.find('TimeCreated').text
            Client = SalesOrderLineRet.find('CustomerRef/FullName').text
            print('    ', WO, TimeCreatedQB, Client)
```

This code is based off of the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#module-xml.etree.ElementTree)